# Renaming a list of files using text input in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I got a folder containing more than 300 video files with names starting from

```
video1.mp4,video2.mp4,video3.mp4 ...video302.mp4
```

I am trying to rename all these files using a text file which contain 302 lines where each line matching the above file name.

```
import os 
def chngname():
    os.chdir('/root/Desktop/video')
    with open('/root/Desktop/vidlink','r') as jabber:
        content=jabber.read().splitlines()
        director=[x for x in os.listdir()[:5]]
       director.sort()
       return content,director



newname = chngname()
os.chdir('/root/Desktop/video')
os.rename(newname[0],newname[1])
```

While executing the above code i am getting the error

**File not FoundError:[Error 2] No such file or directory**

How to solve this error ?
Regards

**Update 1 :**
Code Updated

Comment: This error means the file is not found, I cant understand the for loops u have in ur script

Comment: @DarkSuniuM , i was trying to return both file name in an order  ,  `video1=first line of text`,`video2=second line of text` ...

Comment: First of all I suggest you to use `jabber.read().splitlines()` so new line character wont be a problem and then why dont u just use a simple for loop to itrate over all files inside the `/root/Desktop/video` ?

Comment: @DarkSuniuM ,  yes.  the code updated and now i got two list each contaning files names

Comment: Again I cant understand `for i in range(5)`, u are returning something in the loop, so the loop is useless there

Comment: @DarkSuniuM , i was trying to retrive only the first five names and files , once its done i will change it

Comment: Then u have to use `director=[x for x in os.listdir()[:5]]`, this for loop you written only runs one time cause u have a return statement in it

Comment: @DarkSuniuM , ok..updated . What about the second part for renaming,why its not working here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os 
def chngname():
    os.chdir('/home/alireza/Desktop/Testak')
    with open('/home/alireza/Desktop/fileNames.txt','r') as jabber:
        content=jabber.read().splitlines()
        director=[x for x in os.listdir()]
        director.sort()
        return content,director



newname = chngname()
os.chdir('/home/alireza/Desktop/Testak')
for id, file in enumerate(newname[1]):
    os.rename(file, newname[0][id])
```

This way it works, the problem your code has, is you are passing a list as a file to `os.rename()` function

This code has some bad practices, Its better to use `os.path` lib for file addresses

Comment: Awsome.. nailed it

Comment: @Karamzov Im using `enumerate`function to get both index and filenames,The second loop is iterating over one of the lists inside newname list, for each files in the newname[1] Im renaming them to the their newnames with same index in newname[0]
You can read about enumerate here => https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate